# SQL Server XML update last node value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there any way to update the `userid` value in the last node in SQL Server?
I have found a solution, but it requires an index value. The node count will not be the same 2 always, it might 3 for some case.

```
<audit>  
  <home>
    <create timestamp="2017-10-16 12:19:28" userid="20" />
    <create timestamp="2018-09-25 11:21:21" userid="130" />
  </home>
</audit>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the XML `modify` [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/modify-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017).

```
declare @data xml = '
    <audit>  
      <home>
        <create timestamp="2017-10-16 12:19:28" userid="20" />
        <create timestamp="2018-09-25 11:21:21" userid="130" />
      </home>
    </audit>
'

declare @new_id int = 150

set @data.modify('
    replace value of (//create)[last()]/@userid
    with sql:variable("@new_id")
')

SELECT @data

/*
<audit>  
    <home>
    <create timestamp="2017-10-16 12:19:28" userid="20" />
    <create timestamp="2018-09-25 11:21:21" userid="150" />
    </home>
</audit>
*/
```